# Divide unlimited balls into m different boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Can I get an idea how to approach this question?

**In a sorted row, arranged m different boxes.
how many can we divide unlimited number of identical balls into the boxes, if said that the number of balls in each box (except the first one) must be greater from number of the balls in previous box, and in each box you can't contain any more than K balls?**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try and work it out for some small and concrete numbers, e.g. $m=3$ and $K=5$  ... as you're going along, you'll probably start to see the general pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the set $S=\{0,1,2,\dots K\}$. Now, there are

$$m!\binom{K+1}{m}$$

ways to pick $m$ different numbers from this set (where $m!$ appears as order picked matters). If we correspond the first number we picked with box $1$, the second with box $2$, and so on, then there are $m!\binom{K+1}{m}$ ways to put a different number of balls in each box. Of course, we want the number of ways to put a different number of balls in each box such that the number of balls is increasing. Now, suppose we have picked a sequence of integers from $S$

$$T=a_1,a_2,\cdots a_m$$

There is one and only one way to rearrange this sequence such that it is increasing. For example, if

$$T=3,5,2$$

then $T$ can be rearranged into

$$2,3,5$$

Since the number of ways to rearrange a sequence is $m!$, the total number of ways to pick a sequence of $m$ elements from $S$ such that the sequence is increasing is

$$\frac{m!\binom{K+1}{m}}{m!}=\binom{K+1}{m}$$

Comment: but why k + 1 not k?

Comment: Because you $|S|=K+1$ since zero is included. If zero is not a possibility, then it would be $K$